# laravel - namespacing controllers and models - lot of code repetition

Tags: laravel, namespaces

Here is the example of beginning of my TurnoverController

```
namespace App\Controllers;

// libraries
use \Turnover\Form;
use \Turnover\StatsByEventNames;
use \Utilities\Utils;

// models
use \Card;
use \GameClient;
use \Gametypes\Dogs;
use \Manager;


// Facades
use \Session;
use \App;
use \URL;

class TurnoverController extends BaseController
```

Since PSR standard says every class should be in a namespace of at least one level, I added namespace.

But now to load just simple models, without namespace yet, I always have to call use

```
\ModelName
```

Plus also same for things like Session, App, Etc.

And also there is a plan to have models in a namespace

```
App\Models
```

So to use a model then will have to write

```
use App\Models\ModelName
```

. Without namespaces all this was automatic - controllers knew where the models and Facades are. How can I fix that so at least models in default model folder would not required to call use statement?

Same for Facades.

Comment: You don't. That's just how namespaces work. If you have a good IDE though importing them will happen nearly automatically...

Comment: I was thinking that with composer.json this somehow should be solvable.

Comment: Or maybe I should then have one name space \App for all my controllers, models. So they would be in one namespace and find each other. But facades would still not be found

Comment: Not that I would know of... I don't know if it makes a lot of sense to put everything in a `App` namespace. I would keep the structure but don't worry to much about the `use` statements. That's pretty "normal"

Comment: actually that does not make much sense to put controllers in App\Controllers and have type more text just to have default laravel behavior except that PSR coding standard says to do so, so I just hope I have some benefit phpcs not showinng error.

Comment: Then don't do it. I wouldn't let PSR standards and phpcs dictate your coding style. But note that in laravel 5 everything will be namespaced....